# Memory leak using ASIHTTPRequest block

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, asihttprequest, objective-c-blocks

I  am using ASIHTTPRequest as defined in the example:

```
  __block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    // Use when fetching text data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];//Memory leak here!!!
    NSLog(responseString);
   [connectionDelegate performSelector:succeededAction withObject:responseString];
}];
```

I keep getting a memory leak here and I have no idea why... (memory leak using instruments)

Any ideas???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted is fine and won't leak memory - the memory leak must be inside the code called here:

```
[connectionDelegate performSelector:succeededAction withObject:responseString];
```

That `succeededAction` function or something it calls must be retaining responseString and not releasing it later.

Comment: Thank you! That problem was exactly as you thought, I retained the received data and did not release it!